# Java - Improper blocking of code within a method

Tags: java, methods, intellij-14

Here's my code.  This should be simple enough.

```
    3    public class Main {
    4
    5    int highScorePosition = calculateHighScorePosition(1500);
    6    displayHighScorePosition ("Tim", highScorePosition);
    7
    8    public static void displayHighScorePosition(String player, int 
         highScorePosition){
    9
    10        System.out.println(player + "name" + highScorePosition + 
         "position");
    11    }
    12
    13    public static int calculateHighScorePosition(int playerScore) {
    14        if (playerScore > 1000) {
    15            return 1;
    16        } else if (playerScore < 500 && playerScore < 1000) {
    17            return 2;
    18        } else if (playerScore > 100 && playerScore < 500) {
    19            return 3;
    20        } else return 4;
    21    }
    22  }
```

The error is at line 6 - the call to the method 'displayHighScorePosition'. 
The error is:'missing method body, or declare abstract'.
On the same line in the message block I get "illegal start of type".

btw, I'm running IntellJ IDEA 2017.2.6

Comment: You cannot just execute methods outside of a block. You would normally do this from a `main` method or something similar.

Comment: You can't call methods like that from inside the class. The line must be inside a method or a constructor.

Comment: Stack is not community to say people "go read books", that comment was pointless, answer the question the best you can.

Comment: I am learning online.  I have a little understanding about syntex, and working within certain blocks, but when following certain examples that are giving during a course, it's often difficult to locate where mistake is located.  I will rearrange and seek help else where.  Sorry for taking up your time.

Comment: @Myszsoda: nor should this site be used as a substitute for learning the very basic rudiments of the language. If we allowed questions like these, questions that ***are*** in fact best answered by reading a basic intro to a language, then the good questions would be drowned out by these super basic ones.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I agree, but answer like that is pointless and effortless. Wouldn't it be better to provide any kind of link to read about these basics instead "go read books"?

Comment: @hovercraftFullOfEels I appreciate that comment going forward...

Comment: @Myszsoda: if the OP clicks on the [info link](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) in the [tag:java] question tag, he'll get links to the main tutorials.

Comment: @Myszsoda Actually, that kind of comment isn't pointless. It's the best advice the OP could get: getting a book and starting from the basics is the only way to learn *every* language. Also, tutorials can be found with a google search, which means that this question also lacks of proper research.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels and that is kinda satisfying answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java program, there has to be an "entry point" some piece of code the should be executed first. How to do that? You have to declare a method "main" in your class. Here is an example:

```
public class SampleClass {

   public static void main(String [] args) {
       System.out.println("hello world");
   }
}
```

Note that the method is 'static' so in order to call it Java Runtime should not even create an instance (object) of class 'SampleClass'.

Now inside method main you can call other static methods or create objects of different classes.

Like this:

```
public class SampleClass2 {
    public static void printHello(String name) {
        System.out.println("Hello: " + name);
    }
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        printHello("John");
        printHello("Jack");            
    }
}
```

Your definitions seem right, but you forgot the main method. So please try to put the lines 5 and 6 into the main method compile and run. It should work.

Comment: Here's the proper code:

Comment: Here's the proper code:
        public class Main {
                public static void main(String[] arg) {
                  int highScorePosition = calculateHighScorePosition(1500);
                  displayHighScorePosition (player "Tim", highScorePosition);
               }
By adding the (main) method back into the code and separating each method into it's own block, that correct the problem.  I know, it was something basic, but that's what I get for trying to take short cuts.